# UWP Listview CheckBox when SelectionMode.Multiple - What does it bind too?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I set my ListView to SelectionMode.Multiple the default checkbox appears as it should - what value does this bind too?

I'm wanting this box to be either checked or unchecked depending on a value I'm setting. I cant find any references to what this default checkbox responds too.
Thanks

Comment: The checkbox responds to a control behavior if the item is selected. If you need to need a check based on all the items that are checked you'll need to go for it using data binding (in case you want to dynamically, programatically set a selectedItems property of a listview). Do you need help regarding this? please elaborate a little based on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The list is bound to a collection and each element in the collection has a Favourite property that's either true/false. I'm wanting the default checkbox to be pre-selected if the Favourite element is true when using SelectionMode.Multiple

Comment: So you basically want to show a checked icon in case the item has been favorite-ed and you don't care if the item is selected or not selected. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you want update checkbox to checked or unchecked according to setting data ?

Comment: Yes I'd like the item to be selected if favourite is true

Comment: E.g if light is on so it should checked and if light is off it should unchecked whenever you visit that page

Comment: You can work on a style for that. I'll provide a quick demo

Comment: Thanks, would appreciate a demo.

Comment: I've provided an answer along with a github link for the demo. Do let me know in case I've missed out a requirement in the answer's comments

Comment: It's bound to the `IsSelected` property on the `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've tried to keep things simpler by not using a style. The below code will provide you with exactly what we have discussed in the comments but I wasn't sure if you want the selectedItems or not so in-case you do, please do let me know in the comments and I'll modify the code but from what I could understand from the comments I've drafted up a quick demo and uploaded to Github [here](https://github.com/ImCarrot/ListViewDataBinding-Stack):

---

The code:
I've used `DataBinding` to handle the `Favorite` instead of the `itemSelected`.

**My xaml:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="MyItemsTemplate" x:DataType="local:ItemsClass">
        <RelativePanel Background="Gray" Padding="10">
            <CheckBox Name="isFavorite" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" IsChecked="{x:Bind IsFavorite,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNameText" Text="{x:Bind ItemName}" RelativePanel.RightOf="isFavorite"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescText" Text="{x:Bind ItemDescription}" RelativePanel.RightOf="isFavorite" RelativePanel.Below="ItemNameText" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" MaxLines="2"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Black" Padding="5">
    <ListView Header="Your Favorites:" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsCollection,Mode=OneWay}" ItemClick="ItemSelected" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**My Code Behind:**
Since i've used `x:bind` and it's a relatively small demo, I haven't followed the `MVVM` technique to keep things simple.

```
 private ObservableCollection<ItemsClass> itemsCollection;
    internal ObservableCollection<ItemsClass> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return itemsCollection; }
        set { itemsCollection = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsCollection)); }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private void ItemSelected(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem is ItemsClass selectedItem)
            selectedItem.IsFavorite = !selectedItem.IsFavorite;
    }
```

The code-behind implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**My Item Backing Class:**

I took up a small quick sample class to demonstrate the behavior:

```
internal class ItemsClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    private bool isFavorite;
    public bool IsFavorite
    {
        get { return isFavorite; }
        set { isFavorite = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsFavorite)); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

> I have used Visual Studio 2017 for the demo and the code that has been shared is leveraging c# 6.0 . In-case of any errors at compile time feel free to share them in the comments section.

Comment: @ShubhamSahu what do you mean? I don't quite understand. if you're referring to `selectedItem.IsFavorite = !selectedItem.IsFavorite;` then please have a look at the `if` statement just above it. the `selectedItem` is just a variable i've defined of type `ItemClass`. This way of in-line variable declaration has been introduced in c# 6.0.

Comment: Okay can you look at  ItemSelected click event , no selectedItem in ItemClass may be something i am not understand and may be you missed

Comment: But why would you use a selectedItem call when all you want to do is click and Mark as favorite. There is no 1 right solution, there are different ways to go about it

Comment: Okay Okay ;) now its fine

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Also, if you see I've put the selectionMode of the listview as None. Because of which the listView doesn't perform any actions (fire events, change visual states, etc...) on item selected, which helps in performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154860/discussion-between-shubham-sahu-and-aditya-sharma).

Comment: @PhilVessey has the issue been resolved by this answer? if yes could you please mark my answer as correct (or even upvote it, if you liked the approach) so that this thread will be closed?